# Configuring relative URL in Gitlab is not working

Tags: gitlab

I have  configured GitLab CE to use relative URL following [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html#relative-url-requirements) and after configuration while running reconfigure it gives me an error.

#### Step1

```
# cat /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/relative_url.rb

Rails.application.configure do
 config.relative_url_root = "/gitlab"
end
```

#### Step2

```
# cat /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml | grep relative_url
    relative_url_root: /gitlab
```

#### Step3

```
# cat /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml | grep gitlab_url
gitlab_url: "http://localhost:8080/gitlab"
```

#### Step4

```
# cat /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/unicorn.rb | grep  RAILS
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/gitlab"
```

#### Step5

```
# cat /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb | grep "auth_backend"
gitlab_workhorse['auth_backend'] = "http://localhost:8080/gitlab"
```

#### Step6 [Stage where error occurs]

```
# gitlab-ctl reconfigure
..
..
Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/relative_url.rb] (gitlab::gitlab-rails line 342) had an error: TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 2 resources updated in 19 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you've run into this bug, titled: [no implicit conversion of nil into String](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/3189).

This file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` needs to have this configuration, `git_data_dirs`, changed from this format:

```
git_data_dirs({
    "default": {
        "path": "/srv/gitlab/git-data"
    }
})
```

To this:

```
git_data_dirs({
    "default" => {
        "path" => "/srv/gitlab/git-data"
    }
})
```

Then re-run reconfigure:

```
$ gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

#### References

- [Storing Git data in an alternative directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory)
- [no implicit conversion of nil into String](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/3189)

Comment: @slim, thank you for helping me out. But Iooking into the configuration file, I see it is not enabled at all. This is how it looks like currently https://dpaste.de/t6Vk